# Save user inputted values from jtextfield to a string that is used in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, jbutton, jtextfield, jlist

I have two `JTextField` s and a `JButton`, one textfield saves to "key" and the other saves to "value"

How do I get it to save this data from the `JTextField` and add to the key and value.

Also, How do I take the "value" of the `HashMap` and add that to a `JList`?

Thank you, this has been troubling me, everything I find about `HashMap` s is strings you enter in the code, not allowing the user to do so.

**EDIT**
This is what I have in the jbutton action performed section: ( I'm using designer in netbeans )

```
lm.addElement(capitalText.getText());
lm.addElement(countryText.getText());
```

(capitalText and countryText are what my two jtextfields are name )

This is the code I have preceding this:

```
private String country;
private String capital;
private DefaultListModel<String> lm = new DefaultListModel<>();
Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
String key = country;
String value = capital;
```

Honestly I've just took different things I found online and tried to combine it to make something work and have been unsuccessful

Comment: JTextFields have methods for getting the current text inside of them. From there you work with that text as you mentioned in your post. If you have attempted anything to solve this problem yet, post your code here.

Comment: I added an edit above to show what I have, what methods allow for this? Just something that I can google to help me get an idea, I don't expect anyone to do it for me, I'm just at a loss of what to search for

Comment: Here is the documentation for the JTextField [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can put the value from two `JTextField` s to the `HashMap` **lm** by using this code.

```
String key=keyTextField.getText();//This will retrieve the value of JTextField keyTextField and store it to the String variable key.
String value=valueTextField.getText();
hashMap.put(key,value);//This will store the value variable with identifier variable key into the HashMap hashMap.
```

You can use this to get the value from the `HashMap`.

```
String value=hashMap.get(key);//It retrieves the value from hashMap with specific identifier key and stores it the String variable key.
```

I think this will surely help you out.

Comment: thank you that looks exactly what I'm needing!! Just having problems with the search now :(

Comment: Vote up.Just ask a new question.If you have more problems